# how to display image from uploads folder in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress

I am just learning to create meta box to upload file in wp-content/uploads folder through below code:

```
//display image meta box
function display_image_box() {
global $post;
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'wp_custom_noncename' );
echo '<input id="post_media" type="file" name="post_media" value="" size="25" />';
}

  //upload image
function update_custom_meta_data( $id, $data_key, $is_file = false ) {
global $post;
if( $is_file && ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
$upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES[$data_key], array( 'test_form' => false ) );
if( isset( $upload['error'] ) && '0' != $upload['error'] ) {
  wp_die( 'There was an error uploading your file. ' );
} else {
  update_post_meta( $id, $data_key, $upload );
} 
}  
 }
//save image
function save_custom_meta_data( $id ) {
 if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wp_custom_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
 return;
 } 
 if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
  return;
 } 
 update_custom_meta_data( $id, 'post_media', true );

 } 
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data' );

   //register script
  function register_admin_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'custom_admin_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_admin_script' );
  }
  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_admin_scripts' );
```

this working & uploaded file nicely but i cant display it cause getting the array something like this:

```
> [post_media] => Array
    (
        [0] => a:3:{s:4:"file";s:81:"E:wampwwwtestchild/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/uploads/2012/12/coffee_star.jpg";s:3:"url";s:60:"wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/image/2012/12/coffee_star.jpg";s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}
    )
```

so how can i display the image file now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the custom fields are saved in **_postmeta** table, we will get it by `$post->ID`.

```
$media = stripslashes(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_media', true));
if (isset($media[0])){
   echo '<img src="'.$media.'" alt="images" />';
}
```

Hope it helps...

And if you want to try this code.

**Upload Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var formfield = '';
    $j(document).ready(function(){uploadimagebutton();});
    function uploadimagebutton() {
        $j('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
            formfield = $j(this).prev().attr('name');
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
            return false;
        }); 
        window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
        window.send_to_editor = function(html){
            if (formfield) {
                imgurl = $j(html).attr('src');
                $j('#'+formfield).val(imgurl);
                tb_remove();
                $j('#pagebackgroundthumb').html('<img src="'+imgurl+'" alt="" style="max-width:85%;" />');
            } else {
                window.original_send_to_editor(html);
            }
        };
        $j('#delete_image_button').click(function(){
            formfield = $j(this).prev().prev().attr('name');
            $j('#'+formfield).attr('value', '');
            $j('#pagebackgroundthumb').html('');
        });
    }
</script>
```

**place this in your theme function.php**

```
<?php
/*  -------------------------------------------------------------
    Meta boxes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   */
add_action('edit_post', 'adj_update');
add_action('save_post', 'adj_update');
add_action('publish_post', 'adj_update');

/* Use the admin_menu action to define the custom boxes */
add_action('admin_menu', 'adj_add_custom_box');

/* Adds a custom section to the "advanced" Post and Page edit screens */
function adj_add_custom_box() {
    if( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' )) {
        add_meta_box( 'addsettings', 'Additional Settings', 
                'adj_inner_custom_box', 'page', 'advanced', 'high' );
    }
}

/* Prints the inner fields for the custom post/page section */
function adj_inner_custom_box() {
    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="myplugin_noncename" id="myplugin_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // The actual fields for data entry
    global $post;
    $subtitle = stripslashes(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subtitle', true));
    $pagebackground = stripslashes(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pagebackground', true));
?>
        <div class="inside">
        <label for="subtitle"><strong>Page Subtitle:</strong> </label>
        <input type="text" name="subtitle" value="<?php echo $subtitle ?>" id="subtitle" style="width:95%" />
        <p>If menu title is different with page title, please type here the desired page title.</p>

        <label for="pagebackgroundthumb"><strong>Page Background Image:</strong> </label>
        <div id="pagebackgroundthumb"><?php if(!empty($pagebackground))echo '<img src="'.$pagebackground.'" alt="" width="80%" />';?></div>
        <input id="upload_image" name="pagebackground" type="hidden" size="45" value="<?php echo $pagebackground;?>">
        <input class="button-secondary" id="upload_image_button" value="Upload/Select an image" type="button"><input class="button-secondary" id="delete_image_button" value="Delete" type="button"> 
        </div>
<?php
}

function adj_update($id) {
    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ))
        return $post_id;
    } else {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $label = $_POST['subtitle'];
    $pagebackground = $_POST['pagebackground'];

    if (!empty($label)) {
        $meta_value = get_post_meta($id, 'subtitle', true);

        if(!empty($meta_value)) {
            update_post_meta($id, 'subtitle', $label);
        } else {
            add_post_meta($id, 'subtitle', $label, true);
        }
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($id, 'subtitle');
    }

    if (!empty($pagebackground)) {
        $meta_value = get_post_meta($id, 'pagebackground', true);

        if(!empty($meta_value)) {
            update_post_meta($id, 'pagebackground', $pagebackground);
        } else {
            add_post_meta($id, 'pagebackground', $pagebackground, true);
        }
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($id, 'pagebackground');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: really thanks... i got it by `$media = stripslashes_deep(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_media', true));`